# Simplifying this infinite series

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series, infinity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{3^{n+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n3n1)

I have an infinite series like so:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)x^i$$

or basically

$$ 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 +... $$

Is there a way to simplify this? If so, how?